# How to reload some constants defined in settings.py(Django) after every time period?

Tags: django

I have a trained model which is stored in redis(cache). For minimising response time I am loading it in `settings.py` while server is started. Model is changing(training) after every 2 hours so I need to re-fetch that in constant.

```
MODEL = pickle.loads(redis_connection.get('model'))
```

How to get this constant updated basically re-fetch the model from redis while settings.py remains unaltered?

Comment: I would not put this in the `settings.py` (you can store the name there, but use some function, with some logic to fetch it periodically.

Comment: I agree, it is usually immutable.

Comment: yes, and on purpose. Typically it is not a good idea to change settings during a run. Most Django components make the assumption that the settings not change. It could break (a lot of) things if all of a sudden settings can change. Imagine that you for example change the database config during a query. Then what should be done with the query in progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think putting this in the `settings.py` file is not really a good idea. The `settings.py` should contain, well *settings*.

You can however add for example the name of the model, such that it is easy to change that part. So for example:

```
# settings.py
MODEL_NAME = 'model'
```

Then you can construct a function that basically acts like a cache, and periodically refreshes fetching the model:

```
# utils.py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.conf import settings

from pickle import loads as ploads

def get_model():
    if get_model.model is None or datetime.now() > get_model.exires:
        get_model.model = ploads(redis_connection.get(settings.MODEL_NAME))
        get_model.expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=2)
    return get_model.model


get_model.model = None
get_model.expires= datetime.now()
```

The function thus checks if the model is already stored in the cache, and still is valid. In case it is not, it fetches a (new version) of the model and stores that. The advantage of this approach is that if your server does not receive requests that have to do with the model. We do not fetch and load a new model into the system for nothing.

An alternative is to have such cache somewhere, and for example schedule some task in a thread to fetch a new version periodically (so not per se *by need*, but *preemptively*).

Comment: Works fine. But have one small doubt on how get_model.model = None this works?

Comment: A function is (like everything in Python) just another object, you can assign attributes to a model as well. We use this to attach the loaded model to the function.